# Get json formated php with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

So I'm trying to replace some jquery code with plain javascript, I have a php that collect images from a directory and outputs a json, I need to post the path where the code will look for the images before get the response.
This is the js I have

```
    let imgpath = '&img_path=img/' + directory    
    loadJSON(dataUrl, successJson, errorJson);
    function successJson(data)
    { 
        console.log(data);
    };
    function errorJson(xhr)
    { 
        console.log('Error :('); 
    };
    //
    function loadJSON(path, success, error)
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", path, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
            {
                if((xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0) && success) success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                else{if(error) error(xhr);}
            }
        };
        xhr.send(imgpath);
    }
```

i get an error that reading the php file

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

this is the php code

```
<?php
//
$dir = $_POST['img_path'];
//
if(is_dir($dir))
{
    if($dh = opendir($dir))
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false)
            if($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != ".DS_Store" and $file != "zoom") $files_array[] = array('file' => $file);
    $return_array = array('images' => $files_array);
    //
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($return_array);
}
```

I don't know what that error means.

Here is the Jquery code that works just fine

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: dataUrl,
        data: imgpath,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){if(xhr.overrideMimeType) xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json');},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post your json too?

Comment: Take a look at the AJAX response in the Network tab of the console to see why the script is returning HTML before the JSON.

Comment: Your php has an error, and the `<` is part of the error message. Peek at the response as @Barmar suggested.

Comment: @Barmar it says "Undefined index: img_path" that means that the data is not sent right?

Comment: Yes. Where do you set `imgpath`? Also, PHP doesn't understand JSON content, you need to send a `FormData` object or a url-encoded string.

Comment: @Barmar it is a simple string, check out the updated code, i've also added the jquery code that i'm trying to replace.

Answer (score 0):

It's receiving an html string (starts with `<`) instead of a JSON string.

There must be an error in your PHP script that causes it to return HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: But the exact same code works fine when requested with jquery

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a URL-encoded POST parameter, so you shouldn't be setting the `Content-type` request header to `application/json`. Get rid of this line:

```
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

PHP can't parse JSON parameters into `$_POST`. I'm guessing that when it doesn't see a `Content-type` that it understands, it doesn't fill in `$_POST`, so you get the `Undefined index` warning.

Comment: Try removing the `&` at the beginning of `imgpath`. I don't think it should cause a problem, but maybe it does.

Comment: no, that is not the problem, i'm really lost here T_T